# Таймер для телеграмм бота

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Нужен таймер для телеграм-бота. Суть такова, что если пользователь не отправляет сообщение 1 час, то бот должен написать ему, в противном случае прервать цикл Код выглядит примерно так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_typer=['text'])
def fio(message):
    text = message.text
    timing = time.time()
    while True:
        if message.text != text:
            break            
        if time.time() - timing > 3600:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'ВНИМАНИЕ! Вы не ответили на вопросы!')
            timing = time.time()
        sleep(10)
```

Проблема в том, что message.text не изменяется, даже если написать что-то в бота. Поэтому я без понятия как выйти из этого цикла. Помогите кто-нибудь

python
telegram-bot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил следующий подход для решения данной задачи.

Можно использовать библиотеку `schedule`. Документация находится [здесь](https://schedule.readthedocs.io).
После того как бот получает сообщение от пользователя нужно создать job примерно так:

`schedule.every(1).hours.do(send_warning).tag('CHAT-ID')`

Где `CHAT-ID` — ид чата с пользователем. В функции `send_warning` нужно реализовать отправку сообщения с текстом предупреждения.

Если сообщение от пользователя все же пришло, то нужно отменить job по тегу так: `schedule.clear('CHAT-ID')`

Ну и нужно создать фоновый поток для schedule.

UPD: У меня получился такой код:

```
import schedule
import telebot
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

TOKEN = "TOKEN"

bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def fio(message):
    text = message.text
    if text and len(schedule.get_jobs(message.chat.id)) >= 1:
        schedule.clear(message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Ответ получен")
    else:
        schedule.every(3).seconds.do(get_sending_function(message.chat.id)).tag(message.chat.id)

def get_sending_function(chatId):
    def send_function():
        bot.send_message(chatId, "ВНИМАНИЕ! Вы не ответили на вопросы!")
        return schedule.CancelJob
    return send_function

if __name__ == "__main__":
    scheduleThread = Thread(target=schedule_checker)
    scheduleThread.daemon = True
    scheduleThread.start()
    bot.polling()
```

Думаю, дальше можно адаптировать этот пример под Вашу задачу.

Comment: TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Comment: Какую функцию Вы передаете в функцию do?

Comment: Я создал функцию sending(id):
bot.send_message(id,'Сообщение')
return 0

Comment: А еще у вас target=check_schedule выдает ошибку, что check_schedule isnt define

Comment: Исправил опечатку

Comment: Выдает ту же ошибку, что и в начале, но теперь вызывает функцию sending один раз и отправляет один раз сообщение в тг

Comment: Я добавил мое решение в сообщение

Comment: Оно мать вашу работает! Я от всей души благодарен вам

Answer (score 0):

У тебя не стоит условие выхода из While(пока) поэтому он будет бесконечным

Задай условие для цикла в котором оно достигается ответом от пользователя или счетчиком который будет обновляться с каждым сообщением от пользователя
цикл "While условие" логически выгляди так: "Пока условие не будет истино"
В твоем случае условие истино всегда

Comment: Очевидно, что не стоит. Потому что я не знаю какое условие для выхода нужно сделать. Условие - полученное сообщение от пользователя. Но проблема в том, что message.text (переменная с сообщением от пользователя) не обновится, пока не произойдет вызов функции заново, поэтому пиши-не пиши боту, он будет считать, что ты ему ничего не написал. Мне нужно как-то обойти это, и я не понимаю как это сделать.

Comment: Это асинхронная библиотека, вызови реакцию по получению сообщения которую сделай тригером
Вообще, делать такой луп бессмысленно, сделай это отдельной функцией которая будет отправляться по счетчику который будет запускаться с последнего сообщения пользователя и обновляться после каждого такого сообщения, все это достаточно легко реализовать

Answer (score 0):

У вас там в коде в `message_handler` написано `content_typer` а надо `content_types`, думаю как раз из-за этого `message.text` и не изменяется.